# How to perform a Join on Django Haystack Response?

Tags: django-haystack

I have a haystack model that I'm trying to order by the a field on a foreign key (AKA Join). I know how to do this using a typical Django model:

.order_by('thefk__the_field')

But this doesn't appear to be working with Haystack. I was curious how I would go about this?

Thanks!

Note:

I deliberately did not add the Django tag since this Framework alters the prototypical Django query behavior (as noted above).

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key field has to be at attribute on the indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable subclass in the search_indexes.py file.

an example would be:

```
    class NoteTaker(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField()
        age = models.IntegerField()

    class Note(models.Model):
        notetaker = models.ForeignKey(NoteTaker, null=True)
        what_was_written = models.TextField()
```

then in your search_indexes.py:

```
    class NoteSearchIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
         text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
         age = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='notetaker__age')
```

The [docs explain that here](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/searchindex_api.html#advanced-data-preparation).

In some cases like reverse FKs you have to use `def prepare_FOO` where FOO is the name of the field that is being indexed. So if you indexed NoteTaker instead of Note you could do

```
    def prepare_the_notes_text(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'note'):
            return obj.note.what_was_written
        else:
            return None
```